# Invalid WatchKit Support - The WatchKitSupport folder is missing

Tags: ios, xcode, build, watchkit

We are trying to update an existing app which supports WatchKit for iOS 9.1.
After archiving the build in Xcode 7.1.1 and sending it through Application Loader, we get the e-mail stating:

**Invalid WatchKit Support - The WatchKitSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.**

Now we are already using the latest GM version of Xcode. Is there some build setting that needs to be done to sort this issue? Or is there some other solution?

Any help will be greatly appreciated...thanks!